# Capitalization and hyphenation of proper noun declensions

Tags: capitalization, hyphenation, proper-nouns

I'm transcribing some speech and I came across

> One of the accusations that certain non-Orthodox Christians level against the Orthodox is that we worship idols.

However, I am not certain on how to style the word "non-Orthodox" properly.

Is there a reference I can consult here? Is there one right way, or are multiple forms acceptable?

For example:

- "Nonorthodox" makes sense because 'nonorthodox' is a normal word, but should be capitalized as part of a proper noun.
- "non-Orthodox" makes sense because "Orthodox Christian" is the base term, but Nonorthodoxy is not a specific class of Christianity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hyphens in words with prefixes like neo-Nazism](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/365159/hyphens-in-words-with-prefixes-like-neo-nazism) (sorry about the example chosen!) Examples from standard reference works given are  _sub-Saharan_; _neo-Darwinism, neo-Expressionism, neo-Freudian, neo-Gothic, neo-Malthusian, neo-Nazism_.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. You can write an answer or close as duplicate.

Comment: I wouldn't write an answer where there's already a comprehensive one elsewhere on the site, and I can't close.